# Why it can't be cast type safe?

Tags: java, reflection

I have the following problem: I found a class by its name and want to do safe cast without warning. But the problem is that even after checking type I can't do what I need.

```
Class<?> foundClass = Class.forName(APPLET_PACKAGE + appletName);
if (Applet.class.isAssignableFrom(foundClass)) {
    Class<? extends Applet> appletClass = (Class<? extends Applet) foundClass;
}
```

Without checking I have the same issue:

```
Class<? extends Applet> appletClass = (Class<? extends Applet) Class.forName(APPLET_PACKAGE + appletName);
```

Did anybody face this problem? Will appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @azurefrog ok, thank you. I will take it into account. I'm not a native speaker and it hard to me to explain my problem and I wanted to show you that it's highlighted and let understand what I mean

Comment: @azurefrog changed images to code. Sorry, didn't thought about this problem before. Thanks for information.

Answer (score 2):

You will want `Class.asSubclass`.

Comment: to be a bit more specific `Class<? extends Applet> appletClass = foundClass.asSubclass(Applet.class);`

Comment: thank you, but why my code was highlighted before? what is the issue? because it was verified to be of correct type but lint showed me a warning...

Comment: @k5_ Yeah, but I couldn't copy and paste the original code, so didn't bother with anything longer.

Comment: @NazariyMoshenskiy There's nothing in the language itself to indicate that the cast is verified. It's all down to whatever the library is doing and then doing some analysis with that, which is not something the language specifies.